# Sun Grid Engine suspend instead of restart jobs

Tags: linux, hpc, sungridengine

This may be a cluster specific issue that can only be addressed by an admin, but when I have a low priority job and a high priority one comes along, the process is killed.

When the high priority job finishes, the low priority job is restarted. Is there a way on the user end to make it suspend on the machine it was originally started on via SIGSTOP or something without killing the process? Unfortunately, checkpointing is not an option here so I would like to be able to hold the job without throwing away what's in memory.

We do have ssh to this machine, so if all else fails, I'm tempted just to do a really sloppy scripting hack to get the desired behavior:

```
1. start the process locally
2. send a SIGSTOP
3. make the job script send SIGCONT and just spin watching the process
4. when the job gets suspended, send a SIGSTOP again
5. when the job gets resumed, it should just send a SIGCONT
```

but I would much rather do everything within SGE to avoid any nasty surprises

Answer (score 1):

The suspend/stop mechanism in SGE is controlled on per queue basis by the properties `suspend_method`, `resume_method` and `terminate_method`. The defaults are:

- `suspend_method` - send SIGSTOP
- `resume_method` - send SIGCONT
- `terminate_method` - send SIGKILL

Other than messing with the default values I can see no other reason for SGE to kill the jobs instead of stop them.

Comment: Is there a way a normal user can change these properties or only queue admins?

Comment: Changing queue properties requires root or SGE operator privileges.